# Does xerces-c have a default encoding and can it be modified?

Tags: encoding, xerces-c

Does xerces-c decode all characters to a default encoding? And if so can this default encoding be user-specified.

While parsing a UTF-8 encoded XML the `chars` argument of the callback

```
DefaultHandler::characters( const XMLCh *const chars, const XMLSize_t length )
```

is no longer in UTF-8. For example the pound symbol, `0xC2 0xA3` in UTF-8 appears as `0x00 0xA3`. This leads me to conclude that xerces-c is decoding the string whereas I'd like it not to. I would like to handle the decoding myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The encoding can be set by [`InputSource::setEncoding(const XMLCh* const encodingStr)`](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classInputSource.html#a7604c9a16a6104bfae0a185f8879c74b)